When I click print btn then receive the PDF URL from backend at that moment How to direct print in the window print option?
When I click print btn then receive the PDF URL from backend at that moment How to direct print in the window print option?
const print= async (pId) => {
    try {
      const URL = `/printAPI/${pId}`;
      const { success, data } = await fetcher(URL);
      if (data && success) {
        const URL = data?.url;
        const W = window.open(URL);
        W.window.print();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };


 <IconButton
      color={quickEdit.value ? 'inherit' : 'default'}
      onClick={() => {
      print(row?.accountId);
  }}
 >
    <Iconify icon="flat-color-icons:print" />
</IconButton>


https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_media_queries/Printing#print_an_external_page_without_opening_it
